# Is there any way to hide the very first label row of a tablix in SSRS?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-tablix

Is there any way yo hide the part of the tablix that tells you what the column names are and only shows the numbers?

[image]So in this table, hiding the first row with all the text and only having the second row with all the numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It’s pretty straightforward, as you do not have any condition to hide and show column headers you simply wish to hide them. Try below settings will help you

1. Right click on the row where column name is printed
   2. select row visibility
   3. click on 'hide row'

That’s it, it will hide column.

Below link for reference.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-builder/hide-an-item-report-builder-and-ssrs?view=sql-server-2017

Now if you wish to hide based on some condition try below settings.

1. Right click on the row where customer name is printed
   2. select row visibility
   3. click on 'show or hide based on expression'
   4. click on expression button and enter your expression 
   =iif(count(Fields!TranNumber.Value,"Customer")=0,true,false)
   Note : In the above expression, replace the "Customer" with the name of your group.

Comment: I am using SSRS 2008 R2 - The row visibility is greyed out on the header row for me

Comment: For anyone else with the row visibility is greyed out - highlight the header row, go to the solution explorer, find the 'hidden' option and set to 'true'

Answer (score 0):

You can go to the Tablix's Properties and in the Grouping section, select Advanced.  Under Row Groups, select the first Static row.  The Tablix Member should be in the Properties window and set the Hidden Field to True.